# ILTableViewCell/UITableViewCell lifecycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I'm trying to rename a UILabel inside an instance of the UITableViewCell class from an instance of UITableView, however, the UILabel is not loaded by that time and so when I print it out in the debugger, it's nil.

So, instead I made a NSString inside the UITableViewCell and set that instead, which behaves expectedly because the debugger prints it out as what I set it.

Now my question is where in the lifecycle should I set the UILabel with the NSString that I successfully set

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.fileLabel.text = self.fileName;
    NSLog(@"filelabel.text: %@", self.fileLabel.text);
}
```

layoutSubviews is not working is there any other method which I should use?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: how did you try this can you put some code so that we can understand clearly.

Comment: Please accept the right answer that helped you and increase your accept ratio, so you can get better response next time.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question- you are trying to add a label to a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, if so then use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    YourCell *urCell = (YourCell *)cell;
    // Configure the cell...

   urCell.fileLabel.text = @"Some text";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I get this error:  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: What are you using xib or storyboard? did you define your cell in storyboard the identifier is what you set in storyboard for that cell ..for basic ideas about storyboard and cell please check http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set it in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method? This method is supposed to be called when you are laying out the cell and this is also possibly where you would be adding the label to the cell.